# How do I write my own web page benchmarking code similar to Visual Studio 2010 Web Performance Testing

Tags: c#, performance, testing, web

I am a junior software tester. I am working with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate for Web Performance Testing. But it is real slow and not enough. I need a application.
How can take "Total Time" with C# code?

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/UserFiles/ArticlesFiles/Ambily.raj_634109476392925859_e14.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to test the performance of your C# code, you could try JetBrains dotTrace tools. They're not free but do offer a 10 day trial, so you could see if it does the trick you're after! :)

http://www.jetbrains.com/products.html#.NET_Development

**edit:**

If you're wanting to test on a more front-end perspective of things, you could look at using **Firebug in Firefox**. That offers a ton of nice tools for monitoring things such as network traffic and usage throughout the page load life cycle.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you're wanting to test the performance of?